# Failed to open a WebSocket connection: invalid Connection header: keep-alive

Tags: python, html, websocket, salesforce

I am trying to connect salesforce change data capture [streaming api] using python as server and want to display triggered messages in frontend using html.
Whenever a change occurs on my Account object, it should get reflected in the frontend.
When we call frontend , the backend script runs and websocket connection establishes and remains open and triggres messages.

I am trying to access it using `http://localhost:5000/change`, I am getting

Failed to open a WebSocket connection: invalid Connection header: keep-alive.  You cannot access a WebSocket server directly with a browser. You need a WebSocket client.

[browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rRGE.png)

But I open the html by right click and selecting open in default browser ,the connection is establishing and tiggering messages and able to see in frontend.
I am getting it if I open it like `file:///D:/Python/Streaming%20Api%20Working%20test/templates/change.html`

[browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIwRf.png)
And my python code also printing
[python terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZLX3.png)

I am not getting why it is not working in my local like `http://localhost:5000/change`.I want it to work in my local.
Any help would be appreciated.

My python code [app.py]

```
from aiosfstream import SalesforceStreamingClient
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
import asyncio
import websockets
import json


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/change')
def index():
    print('In index')
    return render_template('change.html')

@app.route('/stream')
async def handler(websocket,path):
    print(f'Websocket connection established to path: {path}')
    print(f'Websocket connection established to websocket: {websocket}')
    while True:
        print("Process started")
        async with SalesforceStreamingClient(
            consumer_key='my_key',
            consumer_secret='my_secret',
            username='my_username',
            password='my_password',
            sandbox=True
        ) as client:
            print("Client---------------------", client)
            await client.subscribe("/data/AccountChangeEvent")
            async for message in client:
                topic = message["channel"]
                data = message["data"]
                print("----------------------")
                print("Data", data)
                data = json.dumps(data)
                await websocket.send(data)
                print(f'Data sent over websocket connection to path: {path}')

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 5000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,debug=False)
```

My change.html file is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="data-container">
        hello
    </div>
    <script >
    window.onload = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("data-container");
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000/stream");

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log("Received: " + event.data);
      div.innerHTML = event.data;
  };

  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    console.error("WebSocket closed with code: " + event.code);
  };
};

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My file structure is like

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PurZ6.png)